# How to customizing line-height in Angular Material buttons?

Tags: angular, angular-material

My theming Angular Material is:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

$typography-config: mat-typography-config(
  $button: mat-typography-level(
    $font-size: 20px, // works
    $line-height: 30px, // DOES NOT WORK !!!
    $font-weight: 900, // works
  ),
);

@include angular-material-typography($typography-config);
```

Configurations of font-size and font-weight (buttons) works, but configuration of line-height (buttons) is ignored.

In browser console I see:

```
.mat-button, .mat-icon-button, .mat-stroked-button, .mat-flat-button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 64px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: visible;
}
/* ... */
.mat-button, .mat-raised-button, .mat-icon-button, .mat-stroked-button, .mat-flat-button, .mat-fab, .mat-mini-fab {
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Facing the exact same issue; Material Design `v14.7.2`;
`@use '@angular/material' as mat;
$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
$button: mat.define-typography-level(
$font-size: 18px,
$line-height: 3,
$font-weight: normal
));
@include mat.core($custom-typography);`
Result: `line-height: 36px` _(i.e. `2*font-size`)_; Expected: either `line-height: 3` or `line-height: 54px`;

Comment: It appears to be hardcoded at `36px`, not even related to `$font-size:`: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/14.2.7/src/material/button/_button-base.scss#L11

Comment: I worked around it by adding `.mat-flat-button { line-height: mat.line-height($custom-typography, button); }`; Adapt selector for other button variants as needed.

Comment: Even simpler: `.mat-flat-button { @include mat.typography-level($custom-typography, button); }`.

Answer (score -2):

I am unclear as to what the issue you are facing here. Can you please elaborate it or create a stackblitz version.

You could also try to edit the stackblitz on the material UI site.
https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples

I have tried to replicate the issue with your given code and it works fine for me here.